# Search through table in lua (Whitelist)

Tags: lua, lua-table, garrys-mod

I have been trying to code a whitelist add-on for my Garry's Mod server. I am fairly new to LUA so any help is much appreciated. I have an Idea for it, but I don't know how to search through it. say I have a table

```
local Table = { Player1, Player2, Player3 }
hook.Add( "PlayerConect", "Connect", function(ply)
       if ply:Nick() != Table then
       ply:Kick( "Reason here" )
   end
end)
```

This is as far as I have been able to understand how to do.
Thankyou for you're time.

Comment: Note: Nicknames can be altered. If an unauthorized user discovers the nickname of someone allowed on the server, they can just change their name to that. You should whitelist based on SteamIDs.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Garry's Mod, but if you just need to check if the player's nick is in the table, you can do this:

```
local Table = { "Player1", "Player2", "Player3" }
hook.Add( "PlayerConect", "Connect", function(ply)
     local notfound = true
     -- iterate through all elements in the table
     for index, nick in ipairs(Table) do
       if ply:Nick() == nick then
         notfound = false
         break
       end
     end
     if notfound then ply:Kick( "Reason here" ) end
end)
```

If you use a slightly different table to hold the players' nicks, then the check will become simpler (`Table` is now used as a [hash table](http://www.lua.org/pil/11.5.html)):

```
local Table = { Player1 = true, Player2 = true, Player3 = true }
hook.Add( "PlayerConect", "Connect", function(ply)
     -- check if the nick is present in the table
     if not Table[ply:Nick()] then ply:Kick( "Reason here" ) end
end)
```

Comment: For some reason,  I get this error from the console saying "bad key to string index (number expected, got string)" I've looked at what the :Nick() command gives. It gives a string, and the table is formatted like a string table so I have no clue where to go from here. Also I fixed the Player Conect not having PlayerConnect

Answer (score 0):

Make a Table of the Whitelisted SteamIDs (do NOT use Names! They aren't unique)

```
local WhitelistedIDs = {
  ["STEAM_0:0:52031589"] = true,
  ["STEAM_0:0:109379505"] = true,
  ["STEAM_0:0:115441745"] = true
}
```

Then write your Code it should be something like that

```
hook.Add( "PlayerInitialSpawn", "MyAwesomeWhitelist", function( --[[ Player ]] player)
if (~WhitelistedIDs[player::SteamID()]) then
   player:Kick( "Sorry! You are not Whitelisted!" )
end)
```

Note that I didn't used the `PlayerConnect` Hook. I didn't used it 'cause we just have the players name there but we need a full Player Object.

Soure: My Experience and the GMod Wiki

Notes: *Used SteamIDs in example are all my own valid accounts*
|
*Code is not testest, pls comment if something isn't working as expected*